# How to search neo4j for a node by a property name?

Tags: php, neo4j, neo4jphp

I am trying to set up some data and am fairly new to cypher queries. I m doing a project whereby nodes and relationships are created as part of a soccer team.

for example I am creating nodes on games and referees only at the moment. My logic is that I read in data for a game and if the referee does not exist as a node, to create him/her. If on a future game i see a referee that already exists that I just relate them to the game rather then creating a duplicate record. I am doing the following and wanted to see if my logic made sense before I even attempted to populate my data.

```
//JUST CREATED A GAME NODE called $GameNode



 //let's search if the referee exists 

            $queryString = "START n=node({nodeId}) ".
                            "MATCH (n)<-[:REFEREED]-(x)".
                            "WHERE x.name = {name}".
                            "RETURN x";
            $query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString, array('nodeId' => 0, 'name' => $referee['referee_name']));
            $result = $query->getResultSet();

            $referee = 0;

            if (count($result)==0)
            {

               //create referee as he/she does not exist
           $referee= $client->makeNode();
           $referee->setProperty('name', $referee['referee_name'])

                    ->save();  
            }

           else
           {
               //let's point the referee to this law case also

               $referee = $client->getNode($result['x']->getProperty('id'));

           }


            $referee->relateTo($GameNode, 'REFEREED')
                     ->save();
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: An SO answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059575/neo4j-php-retrieve-node

Answer (score 1):

This should work but does a lot of roundtrips.

You can use Cypher only for this task:

Neo4j 1.9 use `CREATE UNIQUE`

```
START root=node({nodeId}) 
CREATE UNIQUE (root)<-[:REFEREED]-(referee {name: {name}})
RETURN referee
```

In Neo4j 2.0 you can use `MERGE`

```
MERGE (referee:Referee {name: {name}})
RETURN referee
```

Please also use better names for your identifiers.

Comment: thanks for the help. Would this work? START referee=node:node_auto_index(name = {name}) ".
                            "CREATE UNIQUE (referee)-[:REFEREED]->(game)".
                            "RETURN referee

Comment: actually did not. I tried the following: START game=node({nodeId}) CREATE UNIQUE (referee{label:{name}})-[:REFEREED{ label:'REFEREED' }]->(game) RETURN referee;    And I am getting multiple nodes created for   the same referee. I just want the referee to automatically link to the game if he/she already exists. Any tips? I will try to read up on documentation meanwhile