# Neo4j-php retrieve node

Tags: neo4jphp

I have been exclusively using cypher queries of this client for Neo4j because there is no out of the box way of doing many things. One of those id to get nodes. There is no way to retrieve them without knowing their id, which is very low level. Any idea on how to run a

```
$client->findOne('property','value');
```

?

It should be straightforward but it isn't from the documentation.

Comment: there is no function provided in the neo4jphp library

Answer (score 0):

Make Indexes on the properties you want to search, from a newly created $personNode

```
$personIndex = new \Everyman\Neo4j\NodeIndex($client, 'person');
$personIndex->add($personNode, 'name', $personNode->name);
```

Then later to search, the new PHP object $personIndex will reference the same, populated index as above.

```
$personIndex = new \Everyman\Neo4j\NodeIndex($client, 'person');
$match = $personIndex->findOne('name', 'edoceo');
```